# how to create dynamic salience in drools6

Tags: java, drools, rules, kie

I am trying to create a dynamic salience in drools6.
My project requirement is to create a salience like "**Sailence (1000*weighting+sequence)**".

Where **weighting == (10-priority)**

Is it possible to create this?
If yes, can you provide any example or links?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed irrelevant greetings.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible to define a salience expression by using variables bound to fields in patterns:

```
rule hugo
salience 1000*(10-$priority)+$sequence
when
    Foo( $priority: priority )
    Bar( $sequence: sequence )
then ... end
```